# Can you run human pose estimation and object detection at same time in Detectron2

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, detectron

Is it possible to run human pose estimation and the object detection that identifies other objects such as cars, animals, etc?

Answer (score -1):

No, You cannot.

These are 2 different models and they will have their own configuration and model weights set.

So, you have to do 2 inferences for two configurations and model weights.